# Swift: clear array in iteration function

Tags: swift3

I want to use this iteration function to check a array, and store the result with new array, and then check the new array again and again...however I don't know how to clear the the old useless arrays so that the memory can be released.

```
func checkEnvironment(environment: [MGLPolygon], seed: MGLPolygon) -> [MGLPolygon]?{
    var newEnv: [MGLPolygon]?
    var alien: MGLPolygon?
    var check = false
    for i in 0..<environment.count{
        if detectIntersect(poly1: seed, poly2: environment[i]) && check == false{
            check = true
            alien = seed
            newEnv?.append(alien!)
        }else{
            newEnv?.append(environment[i])
        }
    }

    if check == false{
        // error occurs on here  
        environment.removeAll()
        return newEnv!
    }else{
        checkEnvironment(environment: newEnv!, seed: alien!)
    }
    return nil
}
```

in the code

```
environment.removeAll()
```

gets a error that says environment is a let static so I can't change it. My question is how do I release the memory form those array? 
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Why is "removing" a side effect of "checking"? Perhaps this function needs to be reconsidered, and broken into separate parts

Comment: Yes, this function doesn't work, I change it, and meet new porblem...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392515/swift-return-cant-stop-the-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift3, function parameter are immutable so in order to change the value you need to add a var and assign into it like below.

```
func checkEnvironment(environment: inout [MGLPolygon], seed: MGLPolygon) -> [MGLPolygon]?{
    if check == false{
     environment.removeAll()
     return newEnv!
    }
}
```

Comment: @hapmlpy, Your welcome if you think it helps then please accept the answer:)

Comment: @HussainShabbir This mutates the local variable `environment`, but not that array that it was copied from. You need to use `inout`

Comment: @hapmlpy, I have updated the answer. Please modify it accordingly.

Comment: @HussainShabbir Although technically correct, it would be much better to refactor this method to return the mutated env

Comment: @Alexander, If I understand it correctly. Do you want me to refactor this method to return the value of modified array ?

Comment: @HussainShabbir That's probably a better approach, but I can't be sure without knowing more information about what OP is trying to accomplish with this code

Comment: True, Op just wanted to know like how to change the element of function parameter. Earlier I thought in swift 3 inout has been removed but you corrected me so thanks. I modified it accordingly.